# Make all timestamps in a list have the same format

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list and would like for all of the timestamps to have the same format (... = more elements):

```
timestampList = [... 
                 "8:36 - Appointment1", 
                 "9:21 - Appointment2", 
                 "10:01 - Appointment3", 
                 "11:52 - Appointment4", 
                 "12:18 - Appointment5" ...]
```

Is there an easy way to make sure all timestamps in the list have the same format(HH:MM)? Is there perhaps a module that makes this possible? I have tried to resolve the problem but couldn't find a way of doing it. I want the list to look like this:

```
timestampList = [... 
                 "08:36 - Appointment1", 
                 "09:21 - Appointment2", 
                 "10:01 - Appointment3", 
                 "11:52 - Appointment4", 
                 "12:18 - Appointment5" ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and a lookahead regex from the beginning of the line. If we see that the timestamp starts with `\d:`, then prepend a `"0"`:

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub(r"^(?=\d:)", "0", x) for x in timestamps]
['08:36 - Appointment1', '09:21 - Appointment2', '10:01 - Appointment3', '11:52 - Appointment4', '12:18 - Appointment5']
```